# Remove duplicate string elements C++

Tags: string, c++11, compare, string-comparison, erase

The problem consists of finding all permutations using k out of n digits. I'm able to find all the permutations, but I'm struggling trying to erase duplicates. I can successfully compare and find the duplicates, but erasing them is what I'm struggling to do. I have a feeling I'm missing something simple but I don't know what it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been staring at this for a week.

Here is the code that I've got right now.

```
void getPermutations(int n, int k)
{
    string str = "";

    //fill string with numbers <= n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        str += to_string(i);  //convert numbers to string
    }

    string tempStr = "";
    string outputStr = "";

    do {
        tempStr = str.substr(0, k);
        int compareResult = tempStr.compare(0, k, outputStr, 0, k);

        if (compareResult == 0)
        {
            cout << "| same | ";
            outputStr.erase(k,k);

        }

        outputStr = tempStr;
        cout << outputStr << " ";
    } while (next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think what you meant to do was to **erase** the contents of tempStr, not outputStr.
2. The call to **erase** is not exactly right. Its first argument marks the starting position of your erasing, and the second argument tells how many characters to erase. So if you want to erase the whole string, the first argument should be...
3. You actually don't have to erase anything. After you get it working your way, try to do it without erasing!

Good Luck!